# Org-mode doesn't seem to be exporting listings/minted correctly

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-export

Emacs is exporting `listings` blocks (i.e. `#+BEGIN_SRC <lang>`) in a strange, incorrect way. Here's an example of what I mean with a simple org file:

```
#+AUTHOR: 
#+BEGIN_SRC js
var dog = "dog!"
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC R 
dog <- "dog!"
#+END_SRC
```

Here is the output LaTeX:

```
% Created 2014-12-15
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\tolerance=1000
\date{\today}
\title{test}
\hypersetup{
  pdfkeywords={},
  pdfsubject={},
  pdfcreator={Emacs 24.3.1 (Org mode 8.2.7c)}}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\lstset{backgroundcolor=gray,language=js
var,label= ,caption= ,numbers=none}
\begin{lstlisting}
var dog = "dog!"
\end{lstlisting}

\lstset{backgroundcolor=gray,language=R
dog,label= ,caption= ,numbers=none}
\begin{lstlisting}
dog <- "dog!"
\end{lstlisting}
% Emacs 24.3.1 (Org mode 8.2.7c)
\end{document}
```

The `\lstset` lines are messed up: they have an extra new line, and they repeat the first word given after `language`.

Here are the relevant lines from the `(custom-set-variables` section of my dotfile:

```
 '(org-latex-listings t)
 '(org-latex-listings-langs (quote ((emacs-lisp "Lisp") (lisp "Lisp") (clojure "Lisp") (c "C") (cc "C++") (fortran "fortran") (perl "Perl") (cperl "Perl") (python "Python") (ruby "Ruby") (html "HTML") (xml "XML") (tex "TeX") (latex "[LaTeX]TeX") (shell-script "bash") (gnuplot "Gnuplot") (ocaml "Caml") (caml "Caml") (sql "SQL") (sqlite "sql") (R-mode "R"))))
```

---

```
 '(org-export-latex-listings t)
 '(org-export-latex-listings-langs (quote ((emacs-lisp "Lisp") (lisp "Lisp") (clojure "Lisp") (c "C") (cc "C++") (fortran "fortran") (perl "Perl") (cperl "Perl") (python "Python") (ruby "Ruby") (html "HTML") (xml "XML") (tex "TeX") (latex "TeX") (shell-script "bash") (gnuplot "Gnuplot") (ocaml "Caml") (caml "Caml") (sql "SQL") (sqlite "sql") (R-mode "R"))))
```

---

This also seems to occur if the above listings options are removed and `org-export-latex-listings` is set to `minted`:

```
pdfcreator={Emacs 24.3.1 (Org mode 8.2.10)}}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\begin{minted}[]{js
var}
var dog = "dog!"
\end{minted}

\begin{minted}[]{r
dog}
dog <- "dog!"
\end{minted}
% Emacs 24.3.1 (Org mode 8.2.10)
\end{document}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, so most likely your Emacs configuration is to blame. Try exporting the same document to LaTeX in `emacs -Q` (after setting `org-latex-listings` to `t`) and see if the result is different. (It works for me with Org 8.2.10 and Emacs 24.4.1.) If it *does* work, try bisecting your init file as described elsewhere on this site.

Comment: Bisecting my init file! That'll at least cut it to `O(log(n))`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved by upgrading to 24.4 and building from source. Upgrading Org alone was not enough.

I also noted that the problem went away when downgrading to the built-in Org for 24, which was 7.9.3, but that version is too low to work with now.